# Discrepancy between tensor product and Kronecker product?

Tags: tensor-products, kronecker-product

I have tried evaluating $|\psi\rangle^2$, both using the tensor product notation and the Kronecker product. Why do the results look so different? Are they even right?

[image]

Comment: The first computation is right. The second computation is wrong: that's not how you represent those states as vectors. $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ are just the names of two basis vectors for your Hilbert space.

Comment: So how would I represent them as vectors?

Comment: Or rather, how would I write out explicitly their Kronecker product? (note: this is an exercise from 'Quantum Computation and Information' by Nielsen and Chuang. It's not a homework exercise)

Comment: Actually, I think I've understood - $|0\rangle$ is just $(1 0)^T$ and $|1\rangle$ is just $(0 1)^T$, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.